# Inner join - Pick out 2 parameters on each row

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have one table named timesheet and one named user. In user I got name and in timesheet and I got userID(ID in user) and myID(last modified by)

**table - user**

```
ID | Name   | Lastname |
4  | Anders | Nilsson  |
5  | Erik   | Stolt    |
```

**table - timesheet**

```
ID | userID | myID | info | order |
1  | 4      | 5    | text | 202   |
```

I want to too see who modified and witch user

Like

```
Name   | Modified | info | order |
Anders | Erik     | text | 202   |
```

How can I match myID and Name and add another variable?

userID = 4

myID = 5

4 = Anders

5 = Erik

```
"SELECT * FROM timesheet INNER JOIN user ON (timesheet.userID = user.ID) WHERE userID=$user";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to do a JOIN use table 2 times with the timesheet table, like:

```
select u1.name as Name, u2.name as Modified, t.info, t.order
from timesheet t
JOIN user u1 on t.userID = u1.ID
JOIN user u2 on t.myID u1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ua.Name,
  up.Name AS Modified,
  ua.info,
  ua.order
FROM
  timesheet t INNER JOIN user ua
ON
  ua.ID=t.userID INNER JOIN user up
ON
  up.ID=t.myID
WHERE
  ua.ID = ?;
```